# Edit field name is different from source field name

Tags: react-admin

I'm working with a form and I need to submit a field that's called "Lang-en" however the field name in the get request is called "Lang".
Now I need to show the value of the field in the submit form using the "Lang" source however when I submit it, I want it to be submitted as "Lang-en".
Anyway to achieve this?
I realize It's not the best api but that's what I'm working with unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [the transform prop](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#transform):

```
export const UserCreate = (props) => {
    const transform = data => ({
        ...data,
        fullName: `${data.firstName} ${data.lastName}`
    });
    return (
        <Create {...props} transform={transform}>
            ...
        </Create>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use URIEncode before transfer。。。